# Paypal : invalid token only in DoExpressCheckoutPayment method

Tags: paypal, express, token, checkout

I'm starting to work with PayPal and my first work is to debug it on our website.

Actually when we go to the end of an order, it works fine but we get a stack in the logs : `"Invalid token (#10410: Invalid Token)"`. 
This happens when the `doExpressCheckoutPayment` is called and it seems like there's no token and no payerid so an error is thrown. All other information seem to be correctly filled.

Here's the debug result calling `doExpressCheckoutPayment` :

```
[DoExpressCheckoutPayment] => Array
(
    [TOKEN] => 
    [PAYERID] => 
    [PAYMENTACTION] => Sale
    [AMT] => 4.16
    [CURRENCYCODE] => EUR
    [BUTTONSOURCE] => Varien_Cart_EC_FR
    [NOTIFYURL] => *
    [RETURNFMFDETAILS] => 1
    [ITEMAMT] => 3.36
    [TAXAMT] => 0.80
    [SHIPPINGAMT] => 0.00
    [L_NUMBER0] => *
    [L_NAME0] => *
    [L_QTY0] => 1
    [L_AMT0] => 4.10
    [L_NUMBER1] => 
    [L_NAME1] => Discount
    [L_QTY1] => 1
    [L_AMT1] => -0.74
    [BUSINESS] => 
    [EMAIL] => *
    [FIRSTNAME] => *
    [LASTNAME] => *
    [MIDDLENAME] => 
    [SALUTATION] => 
    [SUFFIX] => 
    [COUNTRYCODE] => *
    [STATE] => *
    [CITY] => *
    [STREET] => *
    [ZIP] => *
    [PHONENUM] => *
    [SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE] => *
    [SHIPTOSTATE] => *
    [SHIPTOCITY] => *
    [SHIPTOSTREET] => *
    [SHIPTOZIP] => *
    [SHIPTOPHONENUM] => *
    [SHIPTOSTREET2] => 
    [STREET2] => 
    [SHIPTONAME] => *
    [ADDROVERRIDE] => 1
    [METHOD] => DoExpressCheckoutPayment
    [VERSION] => 72.0
    [USER] => ****
    [PWD] => ****
    [SIGNATURE] => ****
)

[response] => Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2013-03-07T15:01:45Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 64adbc2375f59
    [ACK] => Failure
    [VERSION] => 72.0
    [BUILD] => 5331358
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10410
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Invalid token
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Invalid token.
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
)
```

Problem is that just after this method is called, `setExpressCheckout` is called and it's a success so the order is correctly placed.

Here's the success response when calling `setExpressCheckout` :

```
[response] => Array
(
    [TOKEN] => EC-5UG654898R029060W
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2013-03-07T15:01:48Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 348b58c6200c1
    [ACK] => Success
    [VERSION] => 72.0
    [BUILD] => 5331358
)
```

I don't understand why when doing a `doExpressCheckoutPayment`, a failure is thrown and when doing `setExpressCheckout`, no error is detected and the sale is accepted anyway....

Is there a problem in the order of the method call ? I mean, should `setExpressCheckout` not be called before `doExpressCheckoutPayment` ?

We're facing an other problem with PayPal and I hope that solving this problem will solve the other one....

Thanks you very much for your help guys !

Seb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [SetExpressCheckout](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/) should happen first -- the token you get back is what you redirect the customer's browser with, and when they return they'll have the token in the URL and that is when you can `getExpressCheckoutDetails` if you need to see their shipping address and associated info, and finally you run `doExpressCheckoutPayment` to commit the transactions.

To reiterate: You get a valid token from the `setEC`, you use this token in the redirect, you get this token back appended to the `RETURNURL` the customer returns to, and you reference this token in any subsequent `getEC` and `doEC` calls.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what I was thinking, the process order is not good. Now I'll have to understand how Paypal have been able to accept all these transactions without any token. Because this is actually used live and it's working fine... Can't get why but I'll have to fix it ! Thanks !